# SQL Query, Join two tables, ORDER BY not working

Tags: sql

I have two tables and I would like to make a query in order to view all the companies from db, and if there are tasks with the same company_code show only the most appropriate to **date(today)**, in case the company do not have a task show the company information and "no task".

Companies (first table) id, company_code, Name, Phone, Email, Website

Tasks (second table) id, company_code, comment, date,

my current code:

```
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
    $sql = "
SELECT *
FROM companies LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT comment, company_code FROM tasks ORDER BY date DESC WHERE date >= $date) tasks
     ON companies.company_code = tasks.company_code
GROUP BY companies.company_code;";
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: For your final result to be ordered, you must put the `ORDER BY` in the outermost level, ie after the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
SELECT c.*, COALESCE(t.comment, 'No task')
FROM companies c LEFT JOIN
     tasks t
     ON t.company_code = c.company_code AND
        t.date >= $date;
```